# What is the correct way to think about a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship with two foreign keys?

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key, one-to-many

I have a `User` and a `Transaction` table:

User

```
user_id (primary key)  
...
```

Transaction

```
transaction_id (primary_key)  
sender_id (foreign key)  
receiver_id (foreign key)    
...
```

How should one think about this? Typically in a one-to-many, I would say, "a user can have many transactions, but a transaction can only have one user." In this case, a transaction requires two users. Does that make this many-to-many?

Comment: When you refer to entity when specifying the cardinality you need to consider entity with its role, not as a class. So sender and receiver are different entities of the same domain and this will result in two N-to-1 relationships: one for each side

Answer (score 2):

It's quite normal that each pair of tables can have multiple relationships between them. You should phrase each one separately.

In this case you have **two one-to-many relationships**. I've seen cases with five or six.

For example, there was a requirement that the payment record needed to include all the users that participated in it, and the solution was to add six foreign keys to the user table:

- Who entered the payment.
- Who verified it.
- Who authorized it.
- For payments exceeding $10K, there was a second person for authorization.
- Who processed the biweekly payment process.
- Who printed the check.

The requirement needed all these users as part of the payment record. There you see six FKs between `payment` and `user`.

Answer (score 1):

A relationship is described from a single entity to another single entity.

In your example,

- A user (from) has zero to many (0:M) transactions (to)
- A transaction (from) always has one (1:1) sender user (to)
- A transaction (from) always has one (1:1) receiver user (to)

Don't describe both ends of the relationship in a single statement as it can cause confusion or overlooking details. If you switch the "from" entity, you are actually discussing a different relationship.

On a side note, I would suggest you name the columns sender_userId/receiver_userId or something like that.  Including the related entity name can help navigate your structure later.  As the content of your design grows, sender_id/receiver_id may not obviously point to the User entity.  A later developer may instead start looking for a sender entity, etc.